# How to fix get package flutter last version 2.2 on macOs big sur 11.3.1 error

Tags: flutter, dart, macos-big-sur

Running "flutter pub get" in car-store...
Got socket error trying to find package rect_getter at https://pub.dartlang.org.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Got socket error trying to find package rect_getter at https://pub.dartlang.org.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...

Got socket error trying to find package rect_getter at https://pub.dartlang.org.

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 3 in 4 seconds...

Comment: can you try after changing your network connection or connect with vpn?

Comment: Wow it's working for me thank you very much 
@TipuSultan

Comment: i'm looking for the solution for 1 week ago not working on.